# Solspace Tag List of Entries

Tags: solspace, solspace-tag

I would like to create a list of entries that have NOT been tagged by with a specific tag group. Does anyone have an idea how to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Hrmm, with ExpresionEngine native `entries` tag, you can use the word `not` to indicate what you don't want to see. It's possible Solspace reused this logic. Have you tried adding this parameter to your tag?

```
tag_group_name="not groupyoudontwant"
```

Comment: Hi! I tried using "not" with tag_group_id and tag_group_name - both did not work. But thanks anyway for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this, though not very practical if you have a lot of entries (for performance reasons), would be to add a Tag:Tags template tag into a Channel:Entries loop. Then set it to search for a specific Tag group ID/name, and have a no_results conditional in there. So your code would look something like this:

```
<ul>
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" limit="500"}
    {exp:tag:tags
        entry_id="{entry_id}"
        tag_group_name="whatever"
    }
        {if no_tag_results}
            <li>
                {title}:
                Message saying it doesn't have tags from this tag group and/or link to add some
            </li>
        {/if}
    {/exp:tag:tags}
{exp:channel:entries}
</ul>
```